# To search a json string value in a list

Tags: java, array

I am trying to search a json string(events) from a given list (eventSubscriptions).Here is what I have tried.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    private boolean isEventsOverlapping(String events, List<EventSubscription> eventSubscriptions) throws IOException {

        List<String> eventsList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(events, List.class);
        for (String event : eventsList) {
            for (EventSubscription eventSubscription : eventSubscriptions) {
                if (new ObjectMapper().readValue(eventSubscription.getEventTypes(), List.class).contains(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

EvenSubscription.java

```
public class EventSubscription {
    private String id;

    private String eventTypes;

}
```

Comment: While the additon of `EventSubscription` is appreciated, as it stands this code lacks context (and I'm honestly doubtful whether it works). Could you clarify whether the code works as expected and give a bit more context on your problem domain? Things like the number of events and EventSubscriptions would be really helpful to suggest improvements

Comment: It works,Consider here events=["Open","Click"] and EventSubscription eventTypes has ["Open","Click"] .both are converted into list of strings using objectmapper and then compared

Answer (score 1):

here are some recommendations for your code.

1) Extract the `ObjectMapper` into a constant, since the instance can be reused.

```java
//[...]
   public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
//[...]
   private boolean isEventsOverlapping(String events, List<EventSubscription> eventSubscriptions)throws IOException {
//[...]
   }
//[...]
```

2) You can use the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType` instead of passing the raw class to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#readValue()`, since you can specify the list subtype.

````java
   private static final CollectionType STRING_LIST_TYPE;

   static {
      TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
      STRING_LIST_TYPE = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, String.class);
   }

    private boolean isEventsOverlapping(String events, List<EventSubscription> eventSubscriptions) throws IOException {

        final List<String> strings = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(events, STRING_LIST_TYPE);

        for (String event : strings) {
            for (EventSubscription eventSubscription : eventSubscriptions) {

                final List<String> list = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(eventSubscription.getEventTypes(), STRING_LIST_TYPE);

                if (list.contains(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```
````